# Capture image on every frame in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, motion

I'm working upon an algorithm that is based on Hand gesture recognition. This algorithm i found and run on Winform with c# scripts. The same technique i need to use in my game to perform hand gesture detection through webcam. I tried to use the algorithm in my game scripts but unable to capture any image using the algorithm. Below is the code that i'm currently working upon. I'm using aForge.net framework to implement the idea of motion detection. The bitmap image always returns null. However using the same algorithm in winform it captures image on every frame changed. I know there is a technique of using PhotoCapture in unity but i'm not sure how do i use it at runtime on every frame. Every guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

**OpenCamera.cs**

```c#
using AForge.GestureRecognition;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Drawing.Design;
using UnityEngine.VR.WSA.WebCam;
using System.Linq;
using System;

public class OpenCamera : MonoBehaviour {

    // statistics length
    private const int statLength = 15;
    Bitmap image;
    PhotoCapture photoCaptureObject = null;
    Texture2D targetTexture = null;
    // current statistics index
    private int statIndex = 0;
    // ready statistics values
    private int statReady = 0;
    // statistics array
    private int[] statCount = new int[statLength];
    private GesturesRecognizerFromVideo gesturesRecognizer = new GesturesRecognizerFromVideo();
    private Gesture gesture = new Gesture();
    private int gestureShowTime = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        WebCamTexture webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
        Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        renderer.material.mainTexture = webcamTexture;
        webcamTexture.Play();

    }




    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

        gesturesRecognizer.ProcessFrame(ref image);

        // check if we need to draw gesture information on top of image
        if (gestureShowTime > 0)
        {
            if ((gesture.LeftHand == HandPosition.NotRaised) || (gesture.RightHand != HandPosition.NotRaised))
            {
                System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(image);

                string text = string.Format("Left  = " + gesture.LeftHand + "\nRight = " + gesture.RightHand);

                System.Drawing.Font drawFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Courier", 13, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
                SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Blue);

                g.DrawString(text, drawFont, drawBrush, new PointF(0, 5));

                drawFont.Dispose();
                drawBrush.Dispose();

                g.Dispose();
            }
            gestureShowTime--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's useless to use `System.Drawing` in Unity. If you need to use that then don't even use Unity as that removes the main reason to use Unity which is "portability". I suggest you use Unity + OpenGL.

Comment: The current framework i.e aForge.net provides me the actual use of hand gesture recognition. Incase of using opengl framwork, does it provide the same benefit like aForge.net?

Comment: aForge heavily depends on `System.Drawing`. If you are gonna use it go just use WPF or Windows form because if you use Unity, your app will only work on Windows. When I said OpenGL, I actually meant OpenCV. That was a typo. You must know C++ to make a C# wrapper for it or consider buying the [OpenCV plugin](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21088). It will save you time and can perform any type of image processing.

Comment: I've used algorithm based on open cv for hand gesture detection, but those algo only implies upon detecting fingers and not the complete hand. However even if i aught to use opencv, the unity uses Texture2D for image processing. Does opencv supports libraries like used in Texture2D?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments (which I am not able to reply to at the moment) those libraries always heavely depend on system.drawing libraries, which are kind of windows only.

What you could try is downloading the drawing library dll (or copying from your system folder) into your unity project (it's managed code, so it'll run on every exportable platform) to keep teh references. Then you could capture a texture2d every frame (rendertextures or so) and draw those pixels into a bitmap which is fed to the library.

Note that copying thousands of pixels every frame is really really heavy. you'd have to convert the UnityEngine.Color to System.Drawing.Color...

This is the easies solution that might work. But definitly not a good final one.